# Trying to understanding protoBuf binary stream

Tags: arduino, protocol-buffers

EDIT: To reflect @jpa response.

I am accessing a server that is generating data via UDP using an Arduino with and Ethernet shield. The data is in the form of a protobuf and I have the the .proto file, but it has been a challenge for me to implement [nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb). In parallel, I am attempting to manually decode the binary stream using this [reference](https://www.sigmainfy.com/blog/protocol-buffers-encoding-and-message-structure.html) - this may be easier for me.

I am still unsure of how to decode this (in HEX). For instance, why are packets 2-9 flooded with FF's? I believe here is where the int64 Timestamp is located. I also notice that packets 12-15 can hold FF's as well, I assume because this is where the float is held.

By default the ProtoBufData is datatypes are: int64, float, bool. But is able to stream ExtProtoBufData: int64, float, bool, **float, float** (extended).

The .proto file:

```
package ProtoBufData;

message ExtendedProtoBufSensorData {
   optional float Angle1 = 4 [default = 0];
   optional float Angle2 = 5 [default = 0];
}
message ProtoBufSensorData {
   required int64 Timestamp = 1 [default = 0];
   optional float SensorValue = 2 [default = 0];
   optional bool State = 3 [default = false];
   // the following represent sub-types; at most 1 should have a value
   optional ExtendedProtoBufSensorData ExtendedProtoBufSensorData = 100;
}
```

Below is the output (ProtoBufData). I notice that majority of the time I received 17 "bytes" but sometimes I received 15. If someone can help decode this, I would greatly appreciate it:

```
PACKET 1: 8
PACKET 2: FFFFFFB3
PACKET 3: FFFFFFE7
PACKET 4: FFFFFFAB
PACKET 5: FFFFFFA9
PACKET 6: FFFFFF97
PACKET 7: FFFFFFAF
PACKET 8: FFFFFFA4
PACKET 9: FFFFFFEA
PACKET 10: 8
PACKET 11: 15
PACKET 12: 2B
PACKET 13: 28
PACKET 14: 3
PACKET 15: 42
PACKET 16: 18
PACKET 17: 1
```

Here is the output for ExtendedProtoBufData. Majority of the time I get 30 "bytes" but sometimes I get 28.

```
PACKET 1: FFFFFFA2
PACKET 2: 6
PACKET 3: A
PACKET 4: 25
PACKET 5: FFFFFFCF
PACKET 6: FFFFFF8C
PACKET 7: 24
PACKET 8: 3E
PACKET 9: 2D
PACKET 10: FFFFFFC9
PACKET 11: FFFFFFDE
PACKET 12: FFFFFF97
PACKET 13: 3F
PACKET 14: 8
PACKET 15: FFFFFFDE
PACKET 16: FFFFFFA5
PACKET 17: FFFFFFC7
PACKET 18: FFFFFF9E
PACKET 19: FFFFFFA3
PACKET 20: FFFFFFC1
PACKET 21: FFFFFFA4
PACKET 22: FFFFFFEA
PACKET 23: 8
PACKET 24: 15
PACKET 25: FFFFFF81
PACKET 26: 36
PACKET 27: 12
PACKET 28: 3D
PACKET 29: 42
PACKET 30: 1
```

Thank you,

Comment: The hex dump you've include doesn't seem to match the .proto file. That message should result in at most 12+5+2 = 19 bytes of output. Can you include the code that you're using for encoding?

Comment: @jpa I edited my original post that describes the system entirely. Perhaps this will answer your question indirectly. Unfortunately, I cannot include code that encodes the data. However, I know that it has been serialized in C# and to be sent via UDP.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the way you are printing your bytes. Part of it seems to be that you are casting `unsigned` values to `signed` somewhere inadvertently, which causes `0xB3` to be printed as `0xFFFFFFB3`.

Here is your packet with that confusion fixed:

```
0x08 0xB3 0xE7 0xAB 0xA9 0x97 0xAF 0xA4
0xEA 0x08 0x15 0x2B 0x28 0x03 0x42 0x18
0x01
```

Now we can decode it manually:

```
0x08  Tag 1, varint
0xB3 0xE7 0xAB 0xA9 0x97 0xAF 0xA4 0xEA   Varint field value

0x08 Tag 1, varint

0x15 0x2B 0x28 0x03 0x42 0x18 0x01 .. didn't bother this far ..
```

Which is not making much sense. I assume that there are some remaining bugs in your printing, so focus on making that work reliably first.

Perhaps try checking the message data in debugger or network logger to verify that your printing function is printing it correctly.